# Keeping client in sync with data from Microsoft graph

Tags: android, microsoft-graph-api, webhooks

I am building an android app that needs to have its local data in sync with data from microsoft graph (even when the **application is killed or device is rebooted**) , Ideally I want a solution with no backend. I have thought of the following solutions after doing a bit of research:

1. Use  [`WorkManager`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager) to schedule periodic calls to microsoft graph, but the tradeoff is that in the worst case, data may be out of sync for 15 minutes (Minimum interval afaik)
2. Subscribe to the [Change Notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks) provided by microsoft graph and run an AWS lambda function which can send a silent push notification to the app using Firebase cloud messaging which can update the data.

   - Tradeoffs: looks a bit overengineered to me, needs backend code, not fully aware of MS graph subscriptions and auto-renewal

Are there any fully client-side or simpler solutions to this problem with fewer tradeoffs ? General feedback on the above 2 approaches is appreciated